# SQL Server Agent Schedule - hourly on the half

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-agent-job

I've created an SSIS package to connect to an external provider and download some data over FTP. They tell me their process creates the data once an hour, on the hour, however I would like to execute my package every hour on the half because I want to ensure their process is finished before I connect.

[image: SQL Agent Schedule]

As you can see, I've created a daily schedule which runs hourly starting at 00:30. Is this all that is required for what I want it to do or am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this all that is required for what I want it to do?

YES!