# SQL Server : how to automatically update data in table after a certain time interval

Tags: sql-server

I have an `OrderProduct` table with these columns and some data:

```
-order_number : ORDER01
-customer_name : Jackie
-order_status : Wait For Payment
-datetime_order_status : 25-01-2020 15:30:00
-datetime_transfer_notify : NULL
```

A customer needs to transfer notify in my order product system in 24 hours if not the Microsoft SQL will automatic update data in column 'order_status' from 'Wait for payment' to 'Cancel'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is with a [SQL Agent job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-ver15) (MS Docs). This is very dependent on the architecture and size of your databases and tables, but it would definitely get the job done. Depending on how sensitive the business is to being up to date, you could set the job to run every 1 minute, every 5 minutes, or any other time interval you would like. If I was going to do this, I would use a query along the lines of the following:

```
UPDATE OrderProduct SET order_state = 'Cancel' WHERE datetime_order_status < DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AND order_status = 'Wait for Payment'
```

Along with this, I would use something like SQL Server Management Studio to create a SQL Agent job on that server that ran at the interval you'd like, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698211/sql-server-agent-schedule-hourly-on-the-half) (Stack Overflow). [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56424/column-auto-updated-after-24-hours-in-mysql) (Stack Exchange DBA) is a very similar question to yours for MySQL as added reference.